# NGINX. How get all request as GET request?

Tags: nginx

I want return files for all  POST  and  GET request.

My current config is :

```
server {
    root         /server/files;
    server_name     files.example.net;
}
```

Currently I return  files only if request is GET.

How can I setup my nginx server? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the correct way to solve this, but it seems to work:

```
error_page 405 =200 $request_uri;
```